# Why "Enable word completion" and "Collect words" settings are separated?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

What is the purpose to have **Enable word completion** and **Collect words** settings separated? (Tools > AutoCorrect > AutoCorrect Options > Word Completion.)

Both settings

- are global
- are stored only in the application and never in the document,

and so once you disable one of them, the other simply stops working. And so I don't see any reason to have them separated. Is it really so? In other words, is it just a UI flaw or instead a flaw in my understanding of how everything works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two options are not synonyms:

1. Enable Word Completion : will do completion while you type
2. Collect Words : LibreOffice will record every word you type
   and add it to its database of words.

The first option without the second, will use the existing database
but will not add new words to it.

The second option without the first, will collect words and add them
to the database. For the updated database to be used, you will need
to enable the first option.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. But it seems this difference doesn't have a practical meaning for new documents, isn't it? If you have one of these options disabled, and then you start LibreOffice, there will be no difference whether one or both of these options are disabled. The difference only exists if you change one or both of these options when some documents are already opened, isn't it?

Comment: No, these are global settings, so they will work the same for existing and new documents. Each of the two options does its stuff as long as it's enabled. The database itself is always there, whether it's being updated or not.

Comment: Here is what I mean: **Test 1:** You have "Enable Word Completion" disabled. Then you start LibreOffice. Word completion wouldn't work, of course. **Test 2:** You have "Collect Words" disabled. Then you start LibreOffice. Although word completion is enabled, there are simply no words to use for completions. So word compeltion wouldn't work in this case either. (And since word completion lists are not stored inside documents, there will be no difference for the next time you start LibreOffice as well.)

Comment: Are you saying that when you disable "Collect Words", the existing database is cleared?

Comment: Yes. It seems the list of collected words is completely dynamic. It is created from the scratch each time you open the document. If you have a 50 pages document and "collect words" option is enabled, and then you remove everything except the first sentence, the next time you open this document, the list of collected words will be about 3-6 words only (depending on your first sentence). There is also an evidence from the official docs: "The list [of collected words] is valid until you close the current document." - https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/shared/01/06040600.html

Comment: Yes, but there is more: "The list is valid until you close the current document. **To make the list available to other documents in the current session, disable "When closing a document, remove the words collected from it from the list**". If you have set this option, then in effect the list is no longer global.

Comment: To correct myself: my previous comment, which starts from "Yes", isn't really the answer to the comment by harrymc that starts from "Are you saying".

Comment: harrymc, well it seems so. To be honest, all these things are much more convoluted and complicated than they should be.

Comment: Designed by programmers from outer space, not by earthly users.